# vanilla js, get anchors with certain attribute

Tags: javascript

Need to get all anchor tags with `data-click-id` = 'body'

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Not sure how to do that with vanilla JavaScript...

Comment: Well, that was minimally helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and the [`[attribute=value]` CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp), like this:

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-click-id=body]');
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do it for you

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[data-click-id="body"]')
```